# Old 9v battery - Strange Behavior

Tags: voltage-measurement, discharge, battery-chemistry

The battery in my garage door remote finally quit.  Before replacing it, I measured the voltage with a digital multimeter and was surprised to find it reading 9.70v, quite a bit higher than the typical voltage on a new Alkaline cell (9.15v).  I put it back in the remote and read the voltage as I pressed one of the buttons, and saw it sag down to about 3V.  With a new alkaline cell the voltage drops about 0.1v under load.

The battery is an Eveready 1222 6F22 "Super Heavy Duty".  According to the [online datasheet](http://data.energizer.com/PDFs/1222.pdf) this is a Zn/MnO<sub>2</sub> "Leclanché chemistry" cell, which is a little confusing as I thought Leclanché referred to Zinc/Carbon.

Is the behavior I saw (overvoltage when unloaded, deep sag under load) typical of this type of cell at end-of-life?  What causes the overvoltage?

Comment: It may not be that the battery has actually been depleted. If it is very old, the internal resistance could have increased. This would give it a nominal 9V when unloaded and deep sag when loaded.

Answer (score -1):

Voltage drop will differ depending on which device you are using, but is safe to say that it should not be dropping that far with a low power garage door opener. A .1 V drop is much more realistic and intuitive. To answer your question it is not very characteristic of batteries near the end of their life to have a higher unloaded voltage reading than before they were initially used; and although the fact that it is used may play some effect in swinging the voltage lower than it might normally drop, it should still not result in a 6 volt drop (or anywhere near that). I think it is okay to assume a defective battery.